# How do I setup WD My Cloud Backup via my Verizon Air Card?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, backup

I had originally set up the WD My Cloud on with an Ethernet connection 3 years ago.

We have now moved to a remote location, and I only have our wireless hot spots on our phones, and my Verizon AirCard.

I would like to set up the My Cloud to resume the automatic backups I have it set for, but I have no clue how to start.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you looked at the [learning page](http://setup.wd2go.com/index.php) for WD My Cloud? There are a lot of resources there. Also, tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Windows 10 Home on a Dell Full Windows touch

Comment: I have spent hours and hours researching. There is no clear answer for a novice user. Most don't even understand the question. :/ Maybe it is not possible to use a WD My Cloud wirelessly without ethernet wire...

Comment: This device needs to be connected to a **local network** to make it accessible to other devices on the network. From what I gather, Internet access is not required. If you still have your router, you can set it up to create a local network to plug the WD My Cloud into (like you had it before, except you won't have an internet connection).

Comment: I don't have a router, but I will get one and try this! I assume my windows support will help me figure this out. It should appear as a network I can connect to and I can choose it. Hopefully it will resume backups. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a bridged ethernet to USB 3/4G link can be done but its not user friendly and isnt an ideal setup as it requires you to leave the laptop plugged into the WD My Cloud.

Swapping the dongle for a Mi-Fi device w/ ethernet is the better solution. If your VW connection is CDMA this must be bought from verizon. Their site doesnt list any suitable devices. If its GSM (has a SIM card) the buy a 4G home gateway, such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P549A48).

Comment: I don't have an Ethernet connection anywhere. Just my phone hotspot and a verizon card.

Comment: Thats *why* Im suggesting such a device. The aircard is designed to service 1 device, the home gateway will service many.